# Distributed generation of random integers with prescribed sum

Tags: multiparty-computation

While reading [this document](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/989.pdf) I came across the following problem. Assume you have $n$ clients. The clients need to generate random integers in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, say $T_i$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n T_i = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. This integers are then used as secret keys, so if $n-2$ clients cooperate, they still should not be able to obtain the secret key of the other two.

This is a bit modified version of the problem appearing in [this document](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/989.pdf) (page 15) in SetUp procedure. There it is not explained how to do it.

The closest answer to this question I found is in [this document](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/802.pdf) (section 6.1), but is not exactly what I am searching for. Is there a known solution I am missing?

Comment: I've seen this referred to as pseudorandom zero sharing [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-00468-1_10.pdf) and [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-30576-7_19). Though in those it was done in the shamir secret sharing scheme.